# Ion-header with mode

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, material-design, ionic5

i am getting error `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'mode​' is not a valid attribute name.` while setting mode attribute to ion-header. could you tell me the right way to use it. Actually i need to set my ion-header below the mobile status bar. Please help me on this. Thanks.

My Code looks like

```
 <ion-header [translucent]="false" [mode]​="md">
  <ion-toolbar class="main-menu-style">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `[...]` around the `mode` attribute!

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true" mode="md">
  <ion-toolbar class="main-menu-style" mode="md">
```

Comment: for this also same error am getting.

Comment: Can you provide a repo or example of how your complete template looks?